# In CTabCtrl can I change tab's icon during runtime

Tags: mfc

In  CTabCtrl can I change tab's icon during runtime?

I have set imagelist to ctabctrl.

I just want to change the image index to particular tab during runtime? Is it possible?

Comment: You should use `CMFCTabCtrl` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
void SetTabImage(CTabCtrl* pCtrl, int nItem, int iImage)
{
    TCITEM tcitem;
    ZeroMemory(&tcitem, sizeof(tcitem);
    tcitem.mask = TCIF_IMAGE;
    tcitem.iImage = iImage;
    pCtrl->SetItem(nItem, &tcitem);
}
```